# Azure Function App(consumption plan) - Azure SQL networking

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

I am trying to figure out how things like Azure Function App(consumption plan so no VNET) and Azure SQL Server DB are connected together.

I was checking SQL audit logs, specifically `client_id` field and tried to match
with `outboundIpAddresses` of Function App, but they differ.

Are there any gateway in between, any chance to get logs of such gateway.

ps
The idea is to understand which Function/App connects to DB within Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outbound IP address listed on the function app are what the function will use to hit external resources, however you may find that connectivity to some resources will go over the Microsoft internal network, using private IP addresses. Unfortunately these are not IP ranges that are published.

If you need to control what IP's you functions use you would need to look at premium functions which can be vNet joined.